# DataTables Date Search and Reset Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Using [datatables](https://datatables.net) v1.10.16 I am performing a date range search as is shown [here](https://infra.clarin.eu/content/libs/DataTables-1.10.4/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).

The search and filter works, however I have added a 'reset' button which *should* clear the inputs and set the table to it's default (non-filtered) state. I'm half way there.

The reset button must be clicked **twice** in order to achieve the desired results. The first click seems to clear the inputs, and the second click resets the table. I want both to happen simultaneously.

Could someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/bwkofdqx/3/).

**HTML.**

```
<p class="text-center">
  <button type="button" id="resetFilter"> Reset Filters</button>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Minimum age:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="min" name="min">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Maximum age:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="max" name="max">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fiona Green</td>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shou Itou</td>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michelle House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suki Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Unity Butler</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/12/16</td>
        <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
        <td>Secretary</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2010/02/12</td>
        <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**JS**

```
/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var min = parseInt($('#min').val(), 10);
    var max = parseInt($('#max').val(), 10);
    var age = parseFloat(data[3]) || 0; // use data for the age column

    if ((isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
      (isNaN(min) && age <= max) ||
      (min <= age && isNaN(max)) ||
      (min <= age && age <= max)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
  $('#min, #max').keyup(function() {
    table.draw();
  });
  $('#resetFilter').click(function() {
    table
      .search('')
      .columns().search('')
      .draw();
    $('input[type=text]').val('').change();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're drawing the table before clearing the search fields.
Try this:

```js
$('#resetFilter').click(function() {
  $('input[type=text]').val('').change();
  table
   .search('')
   .columns().search('')
   .draw();
});
```

Comment: So easy! Thanks :)